# Realizar pull de solo los archivos que no he modificado en local -GIT

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit

Realizé unos cambios en mi repo local en portatil sin hacer un pull primero, entonces ahora necesito hacer un pull que solo me sobreescriba los archivos que no he modificado, y quedarme con los locales modificados y si se han creado en el remoto nuevos archivos pues también obtenerlos

Comment: Confirma tus cambios y después haz un fetch y ese lo mezclas con el origin de tu rama.

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo del supuesto caso de que se hayan hecho modificaciones tanto en el repo remoto como en tu repo local, es decir, que ambos repos tengan modificaciones, puede que en algunos casos haya conflictos en los archivos. Lo que deberías hacer es lo siguiente:

```
git fetch origin master
```

Esto traerá todas las modificaciones del repo remoto pero no las mezclará con tu repo local. En este momento puedes hacer `git status` y te saldrá algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 2 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Esto quiere decir que tienes cambios distintos en tu rama local y en tu rama remota. Este es el punto en el que tienes que mezclar las ramas ("hacer un merge") para ello puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
git merge origin/master
```

Y saldrá un mensaje parecido a lo siguiente:

```
Auto-merging 2
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in 2
Auto-merging 1
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in 1
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Esto quiere decir que para poder mezclarlo todo tendrás que solucionar los conflictos en los ficheros que hayas modificado en local y tambien se hayan tocado en el remoto. Para ello puedes valerte de la ayuda de un IDE. En mi caso, utilicé atom desde el mismo punto en la terminal. `atom ./` y solucioné los conlfictos.
Los conflictos te saldrán en un formato similar al siguiente en cada fichero (en mi caso solo modifique una linea):

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
1modificado 
=======
12312312 modificado en locaoldfafasfa
>>>>>>> origin/master
```

Para solucionarlo solo tienes que quedarte con la línea que más te convenga y borrar todo quedandote solo con el fragmento que desees, por ejemplo dejar lo anterior así:

```
12312312 modificado en locaoldfafasfa
```

Una vez soluciones todos los conflictos en todos los ficheros que hayan conflictos, en este punto, los archivos que nuevos que no existan en el remoto no se tocarán y los archivos nuevos en el remoto que no tengas tu ya los habrás obtenido al hacer el fetch. Es el momento de hacer un commit nuevo, para ello, despues de resolver todos los conflictos, realizas `git add *` y a la hora de hacer `git commit` te saldrá automáticamente un commit parecido al siguiente:

```
Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'

# Conflicts:
#       1
#       2
#
# It looks like you may be committing a merge.
# If this is not correct, please remove the file
#       .git/MERGE_HEAD
# and try again.


# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 2 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
#   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
#
```

Este commit es el resultado de un merge (una mezcla) en el cual han habido conflictos pero ya se han solucionado.
Una vez realizado el commit, ya lo puedes subir al remoto sin problema con `git push` o `git push origin master`

En este punto es bueno destacar que el comando `git pull` es una combinación de un `git fetch` y un `git merge` todo a la vez. Por eso en estas situaciones es mejor hacer uno primero y el otro despues, para tener un mayor control y conocimiento de todo lo que estas haciendo en el repo.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás trabajando con algunos ficheros locales y quieres traer los cambios del repositorio remoto sin perder el trabajo actual, puedes seguir estos pasos:

1. Guarda tus cambios locales "provisionalmente":

   git stash
2. Haz el *pull* para traerte las actualizaciones del repo remoto:

   git pull
3. Recupera los cambios de tus ficheros locales:

   git stash apply